# UITableViewCell Class Layout is not working programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

What I'm asking is that when I change constraint programattically the output is coming wrong but if same constraint is changed in story board output is perfect for more I'm uploading picture.

[Change of constraints programmatically and the output is smashed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPvsD.png)

[Change the constraint with same constant '0' in storyboard and o/p is perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNtEg.png)

This is my code a particular cell:

```
@IBOutlet var imageView1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageView2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageView3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageView4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageView5: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var bttnImageCover1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var bttnImageCover2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var bttnImageCover3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var bttnImageCover4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var bttnImageCover5: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var image1HeightCR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image1HeightRR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image2HeightCR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image2HeightRR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image3HeightCR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image3HeightRR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image4HeightCR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image4HeightRR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image5HeightCR: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var image5HeightRR: NSLayoutConstraint!

/* StoryBoard Outlets End */

var imagesArr               =   [UIImageView]()
var imagesConstraintsArr    =   [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var imagesRRConstraintsArr  =   [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var bttnCoverArr    =   [UIButton]()
var totalImages     =   Int()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    imagesArr       =   [imageView1,imageView2,imageView3,imageView4,imageView5]
    imagesConstraintsArr    =   [image1HeightCR,image2HeightCR,image3HeightCR,image4HeightCR,image5HeightCR]
    imagesRRConstraintsArr  =   [image1HeightRR,image2HeightRR,image3HeightRR,image4HeightRR,image5HeightRR]

    bttnCoverArr            =   [bttnImageCover1,bttnImageCover2,bttnImageCover3,bttnImageCover4,bttnImageCover5]

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    print("totalImages in Static cell:\(totalImages)")
    for i in (totalImages..<imagesConstraintsArr.count){
        print("i:\(i)")
        imagesConstraintsArr[i].constant    =   0 **strong text**// This is the devil. I want to change it to 0 to make it disappear but it stretching his upper neighbour view.  
        imagesRRConstraintsArr[i].constant  =   0 **strong text**// Another brother of devil
    }
}
```

Comment: try to put layoutIfNeeded() at the end of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire `imageView.layoutIfNeeded` after you update the `NSLayoutConstraint` in your for loop on your `UIImageViews` that you want to update the constraints on.

Comment: Thank You for your help.

Comment: @NaveenKumawat No problem, remember to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem so the community can see it solved. GL

Comment: Less than 15 reputation my vote'll not be displayed publicly.